# Get int value from Dictionary<string,string>

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.8

I have an `AssignApiPollerParameters` method which gets `Dictionary<string,string>` configuration and its ok for my other methods, but I have the method `ExtractPollingInterval` which returns int.

How can I fix this conflict and get it from dictionary or maybe convert it?

```
public ApiPollerTemplateParameters AssignApiPollerParameters(Dictionary<string, string> configuration)
{
    return SetBaseProperties<ApiPollerTemplateParameters>(
    new ApiPollerTemplateParameters {PollingInterval = ExtractPollingInterval(configuration)});
}

private static int ExtractPollingInterval(IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> configuration)
{
    int pollingInterval;
    return configuration.TryGetValue(PollingIntervalProperty, out pollingInterval ) ? pollingInterval : 0;
}
```

Comment: So, your question is basically how to convert a string to an int?

Comment: You can use `int.TryParse(string)` or `int.Parse(string)` or `Convert.ToInt32(object)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first get the value as a string and convert this to an int. A simple sample is:

```
private static int ExtractPollingInterval(IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> configuration)
{
    string pollingInterval;
    return configuration.TryGetValue(PollingIntervalProperty, out pollingInterval) 
      ? int.Parse(pollingInterval) 
      : 0;
}
```

The code above reads the string from the dictionary and uses `int.Parse` to read an integer from the string. Please note that `int.Parse` will throw an error, if the string does not contain a valid integer. This might also depend on regional settings.

In order to cope with invalid values, you can use `int.TryParse`, e.g.

```
private static int ExtractPollingInterval(IReadOnlyDictionary<string, string> configuration)
{
    string pollingIntervalStr;
    if (!configuration.TryGetValue(PollingIntervalProperty, out pollingIntervalStr))
    {
      return 0; // No value provided at all
    }
    // Value provided, but maybe not a valid integer
    return int.TryParse(pollingIntervalStr, out var pollingInterval)
      ? pollingInterval 
      : 0;
}
```

There are various overloads for [`int.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?view=net-6.0) and [`int.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=net-6.0) that offer parameters for regional settings.

Comment: To manage the bad format excpetion and eventually give a default value use `int.TryParse`

Comment: @MarcoBeninca thanks for pointing this out; I've added a sample.